# operation with Less

Tags: css, less

I have these simply css rules:

```
.background {background-image : url(pics/bg.png)}

.background.one {background-position: -10px -10px}
.background.two {background-position: -20px -20px}
```

I'm  trying to figure how define a new css rule (ie .newRule) that subtracts 10px on both position-x and position-y using Less.

So if I use class="background one newRule" the compiled css rule will be:

```
{
    background-image : url(pics/bg.png);
    background-position: -20px -20px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for dynamically changing the existing position by just providing newRule , I do not think that's possible.

Following .less code can subtract 10 or any other desired number from the background and you can use that css class while designing your html output.

```
.background
{
    background-image : url(pics/bg.png);
}

.newrule(@val:0)
{
    .background;
    background-position: (-10px - @val) (-10px - @val);
}

.background-one

{
    .newrule();
}

.background-two

{
    .newrule(10);
}

.background-three

{
    .newrule(20);
}
```

Comment: very useful but not exactly what I'm looking for. As you said I need a class or other css solution to dynamically subtract 10px to another css hrMany, many thx anyway :)